# How to link the suggested words in a predefined address of the autocomplete jQuery script?

Tags: jquery, json

I am using the jQuery autocomplete script with category. For my application there are two possible ways of using the form.

1. When a user clicks on a suggested word then it will automatically takes him to a predefined address. I mean it works like a link. The predefined url is

   www.domain.com/index.php?s=AND THE SUGGESTED WORD.
2. The user does not clicks on a suggested word but rather hit the submit button for it's own word. This is ok with me.

My problem is how can to add this option to the current script ?

Instead of showing here the code I put it into jsFiddle for better understanding.

http://jsfiddle.net/pkFCF/26/

You can see it also in the jQuery page at

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#categories

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do (if i understand correctly, when the word is selected, redirect) :

```
$("#search").catcomplete({
    source: data,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        window.location.href= "www.domain.com/index.php?s=" + escape(ui.item.label);
    }
});
```

if you need to to different things if the user clicks the value or press submit you coulkd do:

```
$("#search").catcomplete({
    source: data,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        if(event.originalEvent.keyCode === 13){
             //pressed submit

        }else{
          //clicked on it;
        //window.location.href= "id_" + escape(ui.item.id);
        }
    }
});
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/pkFCF/27/

Comment: Hi there. Thank you for your solution. I have accepted your answer but please tell me about my updated question.

Comment: You should post also your index.php file. I think you'd better open a new question

Comment: Index is just a results page that gets the $s and uses it to get the results from mySQL. The problem is with the search.php

Comment: I posted it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897049/having-problem-to-use-a-remote-file-into-the-autocomplete-jquery-json-script Thanks again