# Easy question on how to write my entries as a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am using a jQuery autocomplete script but the problem is I do not know what to add correctly inside the search.php file.

**this is tutorial jQuery**

```
<?php
$q = strtolower($_GET["q"]);
if (!$q) return;
$items = array(
    "Peter Pan"=>"peter@pan.de",
    "Molly"=>"molly@yahoo.com",
    "Dr. Write"=>"write@writable.com"
);

$result = array();
foreach ($items as $key=>$value) {
    if (strpos(strtolower($key), $q) !== false) {
        array_push($result, array(
            "name" => $key,
            "to" => $value
        ));
    }
}
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

**a working JSON for this jquery is as follow**

```
    [
        {
        label: "anna c13",
        category: "Products"},
    {
        label: "john black",
        category: "Products"},
    {
        label: "anders andersson",
        category: "People"}
    ]
```

How can I convert my JSON into array like above?

Thank you.

Comment: [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) rides *again*.

Comment: The PHP that you edited out took user input and put it directly into an SQL query, which is a massive security problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP should create an Array which itself contains a series of associative arrays. You should then pass that through `json_encode` and send it to the browser.

**Run the code**

http://codepad.org/ibD8kGWG

**Code**

```
<?php
//outer array
$responseCollection = Array();


//logic to ceate inner arrays:
for( $i = 1; $i < 5; $i++ )
{
  $responseCollection[] = Array(
    'label' => 'label ' . $i,
    'category' => 'category ' . $i
  );
}

//json encode it
$json = json_encode( $responseCollection );

echo $json;
```

Comment: I see. Thank you for this. I will have a predefined series of arrays. I found this link http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/demo/emails.phps that does the same thing. My question is how do I change the arrays into that I want? I mean `'label' => 'product',
'category' => 'phones'` and the next array `'label' => 'product2',
'category' => 'tv'`. I accepted your answer, thanks again.

Comment: I can't really give much more of a detailed answer as I do not know any project-specific info about what you're implementing. Do you have a working knowledge of PHP?

Comment: What I asked for is an example that uses the values of JSON I posted so it would be great if you show me those as an example instead.